# How to call method or some part of code from one class to another?

Tags: android, admob

Okay, How do you write code if you need same thing again? Like In my case I have implemented a Fullscreen ad like below code and I need same thing in another activity when button press but I don't want to write all the code, I want to call is from previous activity.
I have tried is

```
 Cover cc=new Cover();
cc.showIndustrial();
```

but it thow me a null pointer exception.
I want to do is Create a new class for Industrial ad and write full code there and call from another class if I need. How do we do simply ?

I have put Interstitial ad on Activity like  this

```
public class Cover extends AppCompatActivity{
public static String DEFAULT = "en";
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
AdRequest adRequest;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxx-xxx-xxx");
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("0F7B337499FCAAA05252B09EFC57223C").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });

}

private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!! ;)

Comment: You can't instantiate your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new helper class class:

```
public class AdsHelper {

static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
static AdRequest adRequest;

public static void showAd(Activity activity) {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxx-xxx-xxx");
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("0F7B337499FCAAA05252B09EFC57223C").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });

}

public static void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

and use it in your 2 activities:

```
public class Cover extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AdHelper.showAd(this); // this will show the ad
}
```

Comment: I hope this will work for  me but I am little confused! AdsHelper is a  new class or you are creating in a same  Activity? public class AdsHelper() ?? Strange.. I am getting error? Don't we need a onCreate method? and extends AppCompactActivity? Please edit your answer to make me clear..

Comment: The problem is I have to make a variable static!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance for your another Activity and later call the expecific method using the new instance but... it's a so so bad option.

Abstract your code creating a new class, for example:

**Your activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

     //...............another irrelevant code

     Cover mMyCoverClass = new Cover(MyActivity.this)
     mMyCoverClass.MyMethod();

}
```

**your public Cover class**

```
public final class Cover 
{

    private static Context context;

    public Cover(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //.........do something or retrieve something
    }

}//end CoverClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Make generic function in any common class and give a call to function if needed make it public static and pass parameters as well according to conditions. Then call it in any class anywhere in whole project.

Comment: I am new to android, i can't understand like this, can you give me example? Like Class  A{}

Comment: Yes sure, in any common class make a public static function like below. I am giving you just example
public static void showAd(Context context){
// write your code to show ads if needed pass other parameters in function
}
Wherever in project you want to use call it with the help of classname. Like if you kept this function in any Util class then call it as Util.showAd();
Pass parameters in it and it ll work anywhere in project.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Cover cc=new Cover();
```

Is bound to bite you in the ass one way or another. That's not a proper way to instantiate the activity.

What I'd suggest is to have a class called `BaseActivity` which extends `AppCompatActivity` and has a public method called `showAd` and then have all your other activities extends `BaseActivity`. This way you can just call `super.showAd()` in each of those where you want the ad shown, without the need to have the same method re-declared in a dozen places.

Comment: let me try it!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Make a class call IndustryDetails write a method in it (with parameter if you want).

```
 public static void getInsustryDetails() {

   //Your code to show the details of the industry.
}
```

> Call this method when you want to show the industry details.
>     eg. IndustryDetails.getIndustryDetails();

from any activity.

Comment: I can't make the method static becaue this keyword exist     mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

Comment: @AppleAppala i can't get you.What do you want exactly?

Comment: Problem is when i make a public static void getInsustryDetails() function  and  paste the ads code then it return me a error at "this" keyword i.e. mInterstitialAd=new InterstitialAd(this); and If I hit alt+enter at "this" keyword then it give me a hint like "Make getInsustryDetails" not static!! Therefore I cannot make a static function.

Comment: Why you are using this keyword to make a call to static function. Call with class name as i mentioned it already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the Ad code in a different method (i.e getAdd), and then write below code where you want to call that method:

```
((Core) getApplicationContext).getAdd();
```

What you are doing here is you are creating an object of Cover class. Now what happens is whenever you create an object of a class (i.e Cover cc= new Cover) the object cc will be null every time because you are creating a new one. That is the reason you are getting NullPointerException. So without creating a new object try to call the method.